# How can I check if IBM i has PTFs to run Node.js

Tags: node.js, ibm-midrange

I'm researching Node.js on IBM i server to see if I can write some node.js code on this platform to assess it's capabilities with existing RPG and CL programs.

What's the best/quickest way to check if the IBM i I'm logged into has correct PTFs to run Node.js?

Is there a command or set of commands I can run to easily check the IBM i environment is ready for node.js scripts to be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write and run a hello world node.js program.

Start the Pase shell environment, from the command line:

```
CALL QP2TERM
```

Create the hello world program:

```
echo "console.log('hello world')" > hello.js
```

Run it:

```
node hello.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling turned up 
[Node.js PTFs](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/Node.js%20PTF). Not sure if this is the best answer though, so would be grateful for any other contributions.

Comment: That page has the necessary PTF's, but if you look at the Open Source Technology page on the same site. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/Open%20Source%20Technologies you will see the Licensed Program options and group PTF numbers that you need.